# pip or conda install requirements with local and external dependencies behind proxy

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, requirements.txt

#### The challenge

Install requirements.txt which includes pypi packages which require proxy and a local repository dependency which does not work with proxy, but this also has external requirements which require proxy to be set....

#### Current dev project

- Location: laptop in local office network
- Requirement type: `requirements.txt`
- Requirements:

  - `https://local.repo.nl/team_library.git@0.1` - does not work if i set proxy
  - `pandas` - requires proxy

#### Team library

- Location: local bitbucket
- Requirement type: `setup.py`
- Requirements: `boto3==1.9.236` - requires proxy

#### Solution

I would like to do something like this, but this does not work:

requirements.txt

```
https://local.repo.nl/team_library.git@0.1 --proxy=""
pandas --proxy="1.2.3.4:5678"
```

setup.py

`boto3==1.9.236 --proxy="1.2.3.4:5678"`

Comment: I do not believe it is something that can be solved only with _pip_ settings, options, or configuration. [The `--proxy` option is not recognized in `requirements.txt` files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format). It's most likely fixable in the proxy configuration, or maybe locally with a [PAC file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)(?).

Comment: Not sure how the [environment variable `PIP_USER_AGENT_USER_DATA`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server) is supposed to help with the proxy. Might be worth asking the _pip_ maintainers. On the other hand, _pip_ uses _requests_ internally, and it seems to be able to understand [proxy settings specific to a host](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies), but pip probably doesn't take advantage of it.